# Creating instances of a doubly linked list

Tags: list, ocaml, circular-reference

I have been given the following implementation of a doubly linked list:

```
type 'a elem = {v : 'a; mutable next : 'a lista; mutable prev : 'a lista}
and 'a lista = 'a elem option;;
```

Using this implementation I'm trying to make some example lists. A one element list is easy to make:

```
let bla_1 = Some {v = 1; next = None; prev = None};;
```

And I guess an empty list would be two None nodes. But I don't know how to make lists with more elements.

Comment: This is a doubly-linked list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list

Comment: I know, but how do I make a list consisting of for.ex 3 nodes 1,2,3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build a list with two elements `x` and `y`, you have to ensure you have two values of type `'a elem` pointing to each other (not counting the intermediate option type `'a lista`). Eventually, you need to have a circular structure where:

- `lx` is bound to `{ v = x; next = Some ly; prev = None }`,
- and `ly` is bound to `{ v = y; next = None; prev = Some lx}`

You *can* have mutually recursive values in OCaml (thanks octhacron):

```
let rec x = { v = 0; next = Some y; prev = None} 
    and y = { v = 1; next = None; prev = Some x}
```

But this gets hard to use to build more complex lists. And that's why you have mutable fields: you can build nodes and then connect them by changing their `next` and `prev` fields. For example, you first define `lx` with the `next` field set to `None`, and only after you know what is `ly`, you can replace the value pointed by `lx.next` by `Some ly`.

Here below is a function that converts a regular list into a doubly-linked list; when calling itself recursively, it builds nodes; when returning from a recursive call, it modifies the `next` node so that it points back through its `prev` field to the current one:

```
let rec to_dbl_list = function
    [] -> None
  | x::xs ->
     let node = { v = x; prev = None ; next = (to_dbl_list xs)} in
     let current = Some node in
     (match node.next with
        None -> ()
      | Some next -> (next.prev <- current)) ;
     current ;;
```

And so:

```
# to_dbl_list [1; 2; 3];;
- : int lista =
Some
 {v = 1;
  next =
   Some
    {v = 2; next = Some {v = 3; next = None; prev = <cycle>}; prev = <cycle>};
  prev = None}
```

Comment: Mutually recursive values are perfectly possible in OCaml, but they are indeed not really useful in this case: `let rec x = { v= 0; next=Some y;prev=None} and y= {v=1; next= None; prev= Some x}` works.

Comment: @octachron Thanks, I missed that!